# Using Cygwin and Django

Tags: django, cygwin

I'm starting to become less and less of a Windows guy and might try Linux.
Is difficult working with windows to do web development with the terminal.

I have two questions

1. How can I *cd desktop* on the Cygwin terminal I see people do this with ease but I keep getting
   -bash: cd desktop no such file directory I'm guessing it has some thing to do with the fact that Cygwin is set up as the home directory.
2. I want to download https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.4.2/tarball/ using wget
   so I did

`wget https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.4.2/tarball/`

and I get an error back saying 
`ERROR: the certificate of 'django' is not trusted.`

`ERROR: the certificate of 'django' hasn't got a known issuer.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first question:

check your current directory with `pwd` and navigate from there.

for the second question:

add `--no-check-certificate` to your wget command

```
wget -Odjango.tar.gz --no-check-certificate https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.4.2/tarball/
```

Comment: when I download it, I get the message saying saving to index.html? shouldn't it be saving as a tar file or some thing.

Comment: thats because of the way the django project implements the redirect for downloads... You can use -Odjango.tar.gz option to save to a specific filename...

Comment: Just curious how do I make cd desktop easily accessible on cygwin?

Comment: depends where this directory is located (absolute url) and where cygwin defaults to (pwd after launch)...

Comment: Just the default C:\cygwin/home/foo
which is why when I say **cd desktop** or **cd documents** it won't go directly

Comment: @Shire Try `cd /cygdrive/c/` and then navigate to Desktop or Documents from there. By default Windows drives will be in `/cygdrive/<the letter of the drive>`.

Comment: assuming that your desktop is located at `/cygdrive/c/documents and settings/username/desktop`, try this: create a link to the desktop from your cygwin root directory like this: `ln -s /cygdrive/c/documents and settings/username/desktop /desktop`.  then you can just use `cd /desktop` from anywhere you like